# ASP.NET MVC4 application using Angular.JS Active Directory Authentication

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs

Im writing a web app using C# with ASP.NET 4.5/Entity as a backend. With Angular.js handling 
most of the front-end/database query stuff. ASP.NET 4.5 makes it really easy to connect to 
our active directory using windows authentication.

However will I run into problems when I scrap all the razor templates, and replace it with regular HTML/CSS and angular scripts. All I really need the active directory stuff for is to create permission for who can pull what file from our database.

Im pretty new to web apps, so far ive like the entity framework alot, but if you guys know a more efficient way (better back end) to do this feel free to tell me.

My app basically needs to allow users to upload spreadsheets and videos, search for them, and only allow access to users that are in certain AD groups.

Answer (score 4):

We solved this problem by using MVC to render the HTML templates. In your controller or directive set the `templateUrl` to an action which does whatever logic is necessary to render the template for that user. Also, be sure to check user permissions in your AJAX calls.

Answer (score -4):

Figured it out. Made a new web api controller

then added this function

```
        public string getUser()
    {
        return User.Identity.Name;
    }
```

haha that was easy.

However if anyone sees any errors i may run into doing it this way. Please point em out

Comment: this is not a secure method. Anyone can read the username and use it to query your site